# What is a generalized suffix tree?

Tags: string, data-structures, substring, suffix-tree, string-algorithm

I saw the Wikipedia page but still am not clear with the idea.

To find the longest common substring of 2 strings (`T` and `S`), I've read that we must build a suffix tree for the string `T($1)S($2)`, where`($1) and ($2) are special characters not part of the strings.

But the Wikipedia image for the strings `ABAB` and `BABA` looks like this:
[image: Generalized suffix tree]

Why doesn't it contain the entire string `ABAB($1)BABA($2)` ? Isn't it a suffix of the concatenated string?

What are those numbers on the leaves?

Answer (score 8):

A generalized suffix tree is a variation on a suffix tree in which the suffixes for two (or more) distinct strings T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> are stored, not just the suffixes of one string T.

One way to build a generalized suffix tree is to start by making a suffix tree for T<sub>1</sub>$<sub>1</sub>T<sub>2</sub>$<sub>2</sub>. This resulting suffix tree will contain all the suffixes of T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub>, but it will also contain a lot of "spurious" suffixes that start in T<sub>1</sub> and spread into T<sub>2</sub>. To fix this, after building the initial suffix tree, you would typically make a second pass over the tree structure and eliminate any suffixes that extend past the $<sub>1</sub> marker. This is why, for example, the generalized suffix tree you gave above doesn't contain ABAB$<sub>1</sub>BABA$<sub>2</sub>.

As to your next question - what are the numbers in the leaves? - each leaf in a suffix tree is typically tagged with the start index of the suffix that the leaf corresponds to. In a generalized suffix tree, each leaf is tagged with two pieces of information - the start index of the suffix, and which string that suffix belongs to. The notation a:b on a leaf means "this suffix comes from string a, and it starts at index b in that string." For example, the marker 1:3 on the leftmost leaf means "this suffix comes from string 1 and it starts at position 3." You can see that this corresponds to the suffix A$<sub>1</sub>, which does indeed start at position 3 in ABAB$<sub>1</sub>, assuming 1-indexing.

Hope this helps!